# how can I scan a barcode in a specific textbox only?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net

I have my barcode scanner..and whenever I put the cursor in any textbox in my project it scans the barcode.. How should I scan a barcode to a specific textbox only..and prevent it from scanning in other textbox..is there a code for that?

Comment: I suppose the scann engine do that automatically. If yes you have to find at manual to disable this propery and try to do it on demand.

Answer (score 2):

Barcode scanner works as a standard keyboard. It will read bar code information and input character one by one. Finally, it input an enter key at the end of the string.

I think you should disable all another text boxes, set default focus to your specific text box. Then, after scan, you catch the enter key and unlock all another text boxes.

Comment: I already placed a focus in the specific textbox..but still it scans to ther textbox when i place the cursor.

Comment: The barcode will always input via the cursor. So what i mean is disable all another textbox, then your specific textbox is the only one can have focus before scan.